# What does amongst mean in this sentance?

Tags: meaning, grammar

"Some children are addicted to video games and their mindset and behaviour becomes more focused on wanting to play games rather than enjoying time with their families. ***Amongst*** these games are Starcraft, Warcraft and Minecraft."

What does the amongst mean here? Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: What does the dictionary say?

Answer (score 2):

Amongst means among.
The 2012 edition of the OED says the words are identical and can be used interchangeably.  I'd ordinarily use 'among' because it's simpler and sounds less pretentious.
Unless of course you want to sound pretentious.

Comment: But amongst is a preposition, can this be used at the beginning of a sentence?